# .htaccess not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: .htaccess

So i have an .htaccess file that has this in it:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/path/to/app/(.*)$ /path/to/app/public/$1 [NC,L]
```

When I go to /path/to/app/ in the browser it displays the directory structure instead of redirecting the server to /path/to/app/public/$1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the apache error logs if you have access to them. Another thing to help you with rewrite rules is [rewrite logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) ... helped me debug some complicated rules

Answer (score 1):

Problem is this line:

```
RewriteRule ^/path/to/app/(.*)$ /path/to/app/public/$1 [NC,L]
```

**Remember:** Rewrite doesn't match leading slash. Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(path/to/app)/(.*)$ /$1/public/$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, still didn't work. my .htaccess file is in the app dir if that makes a difference.

Comment: And what is your DOCUMENT_ROOT set to? Is it one dor above app dir?

Answer (score 0):

I think you try build Symfony application? To rewrite rule you need allow override in httpd.conf

```
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/symfony/web"

 <Directory "/var/www/symfony/web">
  allow from all
  AllowOverride All  <-------------
  Options +Indexes
 </Directory>
```

And if you use directive

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

that mean that `if` directory exist `then` display structure `else` use other RewriteRule

Also try

```
RewriteRule ^/path/to/app/(.*)$ /path/to/app/public/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I don't have access to the virtualhost

Comment: you can write it in .htaccess file